# DDBLockClient - Non leaders wont compete for leadership after failing first time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using [dynamoDBLockClient][1] to choose the leader host

**Expectation :**

If  host is dead new host should become leader in next 12 seconds

Followed this:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/

https://github.com/amazon-archives/dynamodb-lock-client

**Reality**

If leader host is dead other host/non leader wont try to become leader. How do i set DDB lock  in such a way that if leader is dead other host must become leader in next 10 seconds

```
@Provides
public AmazonDynamoDBLockClient getLeaderSelectionLockClient(AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB) {
  final AmazonDynamoDBLockClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBLockClient(
    AmazonDynamoDBLockClientOptions.builder(dynamoDB, LEADER_SELECTION_DDB_TABLE)
        .withTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .withLeaseDuration(10L)
        .withHeartbeatPeriod(3L)
        .withOwnerName(EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId())
        .withCreateHeartbeatBackgroundThread(true) //If true then leader will continue to be leader till it die
        .build());

  return client;
}

@Provides
public AcquireLockOptions getAcquireLockOptionsForEnchanter() {
    final String keyToLock = "LEADER";
    AcquireLockOptions acquireLockOptions = AcquireLockOptions
        .builder(keyToLock)
        .withRefreshPeriod(11L)
        .withTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
    return acquireLockOptions;
}

public void competeForLeadership() {

    final String lockSuccessMessage =
        "Acquired lock! If I die, my lock will expire in 10 seconds Otherwise, I will hold it until I stop "
            + "heart beating." + EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId();
    try {
        final Optional<LockItem> lockItem = dynamoDBLockClient.tryAcquireLock(acquireLockOptions);

        if (lockItem.isPresent()) {
            log.info(lockSuccessMessage);
        } else {
            log.error("Failed to acquire lock!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Leader Selector is down");
    }
}
```

As per document https://www.mvndoc.com/c/com.amazonaws/dynamodb-lock-client/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AcquireLockOptions.AcquireLockOptionsBuilder.html#withAdditionalTimeToWaitForLock-java.lang.Long-

`withRefreshPeriod` should have solved this problem but it is not solving.

How to do set up correctly?

Looks like `tryAcquire` is non blocking call since I can see control is coming back to code after failed to get lock with message `"Failed to acquire lock!"`

Is it possible to keep on retrying till it get lock

Thanks

Jk

Comment: Where do you call `competeForLeadership`? You should have a loop/timer that calls this method repeatedly until it acquires the lock.  It's unclear from your question what your design is but if you want to just block and wait until you become leader, then just write a loop that tries to acquire the lock and if it fails, it sleeps for a few seconds and tries again.

Comment: Thanks for answer. competeForLeadership - is called once by different method. Loop will work since AcquieOption has one option "withShouldSkipBlockingWait" . https://github.com/amazon-archives/dynamodb-lock-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AcquireLockOptions.java. so i thought it is by default blocking call